# On page live search (instant updating)

Tags: jquery, search

I'd like to use a google instant like search for my website my url is http://gamersweb.net/games

all the content that is going to be searched is going to exist on that page it's not pulling it from a database or anything.

Awhile back I was browsing random jquery plugins and I saw this really cool apple-like plugin that could use all the thumbnails and sort them, change their sizes and search through them and it was all animated very cool. I didn't bookmark it and I can't seem to find it. But that maybe my solution, however, anything will do. I was thinking it maybe possible to assign 'rel' tags to all of my 'img' tags and use a search to located the appropriate rel tag based on the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will help you

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shankar, can this be used with an img alt, title or rel tags or will i have to use hidden txt? Id like to keep this page as simple as possible

Comment: I'm just going to use this, thanks a lot man! looks good ;) http://gamersweb.net/games

Comment: How we can do for large lists? For example, I'm with 10 elements it works like a charm, but with 10.000, it goes really slow

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do with Ajax, PHP and JQuery. Hope this helps or gives you a start.

See live demo and source code here.

http://purpledesign.in/blog/to-create-a-live-search-like-google/

Create a search box, may be an input field like this.

```
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
```

Now we need listen to whatever the user types on the text area. For this we will use the jquery live() and the keyup event. On every keyup
we have a jquery function “search” that will run a php script.

Suppose we have the html like this. We have an input field and a list to display the results.

```
 <div class="icon"></div>
 <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
 <ul id="results"></ul>
```

We have a Jquery script that will listen to the keyup event on the input field and if it is not empty it will invoke the search() function. The
search() function will run the php script and display the result on the same page using AJAX.

Here is the JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    //Listen for the event
        $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });


    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_st.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);

                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }



});
```

In the php, shoot a query to the mysql database. The php will return the results that will be put into the html using AJAX. Here the result is put into
a html list.

Suppose there is a dummy database containing two tables animals and bird with two similar column names ‘type’ and ‘desc’.

```
 //search.php

// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "live";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;

$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<li class="result">';
    $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
    $html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
    $html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
    $html .= '</a>';
    $html .= '</li>';
     $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
    $search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = "SELECT *
     FROM animals
     WHERE type LIKE '%".$search_string."%'
     UNION ALL SELECT *
     FROM birf
     WHERE type LIKE '%".$search_string."%'"
     ;
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
        while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array[] = $results;
        }

        // Check If We Have Results
        if (isset($result_array)) {
            foreach ($result_array as $result) {

                // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
                $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['desc']);
                $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['type']);
            $display_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($result['type']).'&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8';

                // Insert Name
                $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

                // Insert Function
                $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

                // Insert URL
                $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);



                // Output
                echo($output);
            }
        }else{

            // Format No Results Output
            $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
            $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
            $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }
```